# array handling inside javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var meal_qty = {}; 
      var label_options = new Array(); 
      var qty_options = new Array(); 


      <?php foreach($label_name as $meal_option_id => $names_of_labels)
    {?>


      var meal_label_qty = <?php echo $meal_option_id; ?>;

      meal_qty[meal_label_qty] = [];
      var item = {
            mon: <?php echo $_SESSION['protiens']['mon'][$meal_option_id]['qty']?> || null,
            tues: <?php echo $_SESSION['protiens']['tues'][$meal_option_id]['qty']?> || null,
            wed: <?php echo $_SESSION['protiens']['wed'][$meal_option_id]['qty']?> || null,
            thur: <?php echo $_SESSION['protiens']['thur'][$meal_option_id]['qty']?> || null,
            fri: <?php echo $_SESSION['protiens']['fri'][$meal_option_id]['qty']?> || null
      }
      meal_qty[meal_label_qty] = item; 
      <?php }?>


      $('.option').on('click', function() {
            $(".tab_options").hide();
            var label = $(this).attr('label_option');
            console.log(meal_qty[label]);
            //$("#qty1").val(meal_qty[label][mon]);
```

As you can see the last commented out line, it says "mon" is undefined, however how can I get it to show the number? the console before it shows normally as

```
Object{mon:2, tues:null , wed:1 , thur: null, fri: null}
```

How can I show just monday which is "2"

Comment: Not `[mon]`, but `.mon` as it is a literal property name, not one stored in a variable named `mon`.

Comment: or `["mon"]` too ; objects' properties can accessed through indexing in JS

Comment: And how can I make the it 0 inside of null for the other variables? @trincot

Comment: There is the define of the js array is in global scope?

Comment: @sarah, you can find solutions for that easily by searching a bit: `val(meal_qty[label].mon || 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either:

1) put mon in quotes:

```
meal_qty[label]["mon"]
```

2) use dot notation:

```
meal_qty[label].mon
```

Mon is not a variable, so it has to be one of the two above.